# VBA - Combobox value is always null

Tags: vba, combobox, null

I've only been working with VBA for about two weeks now so if I call things by the wrong name, sorry. Anyway, I've been having trouble with a combobox.  the box is filled with items and I can see them, scroll through them and click them. However, when I click the button I have that checks the value of the combobox, no matter what item I have selected in it, the value always comes out to null and is caught by

```
If IsNull(ToolReportBox.Value) = True Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter a tool"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

If I don't have this check in there and try to assign the value to a sting such as

```
Dim toolName_str As String
    toolName_str = ToolReportBox.Value
```

later in the program it throws the error  "Run-time error '94':  Invalid use of Null"

anyone got suggestions other than make it a listbox?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have the Bound Column property in the Data tab set for a column that has data in it.  For example, if you have it set for 1, it will look at the RowSource and grab the value from the first column listed there.  Make sure that column has data in it.

Comment: I have 6 other comboboxes that didn't need that, but that was exactly the problem.  thanks for the quick reply, it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

check the values in your combo box - `forms!frmName!ToolReportBox.column(0)` (and then increase to 1,2,3 however many columns are in your combo box) - this is just in case what you are seeing is not actually the value being returned.

This usually occurs when the `ListWidth` in the combo box properties has a zero in there